# How to run a script as soon as a network interface is created?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, network-manager, udev

I use VirtualBox 5.1 on Ubuntu 16.04 Xenial with some VMs on *"Host-Only"* network that appears as `vboxnet0` network interface in the host. I want to start up `dnsmasq` with a custom config to serve DNS and DHCP on this `vboxnet0` network as soon as the interface is created, which is when VirtualBox app is run.

Can trigger this `dnsmasq` startup somehow? Through NetworkManager or udev or systemd?

BTW I don't want to use the VirtualBox built-in DNS/DHCP server for reasons beyond the scope of this question (essentially custom DHCP options and redirected some DNS queries for the VMs).

Also I can't start `dnsmasq` *before* `vboxnet0` is created becuase it must be run with `--bind-interfaces` due to NetworkManager already running one instance of `dnsmasq` for it own purposes.

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20478516/how-to-detect-when-networking-initialized-in-etc-init-d-script

Answer (score 0):

Functionality of running specific commands when an interface goes up/down is provided out of the box most *nix systems. However running a command when an interface is created *might* require some custom scripts.

One way to do this (not sure if it is the best way) would be to write custom script which periodically scans the output of `ifconfig` command and checks if it contains an entry for `vboxnet0` and runs your custom command if an entry for `vboxnet0` interface is found.